# How to check if a lens is clean by taking some images

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I have several lenses that I need to make sure they are clean.

I need to write  software to do this as I want to have a quick and subjective free way of doing this.

I know that when the lens is not clean, there is always a very faint pattern on the lens, so I am wondering how I can detect this faint pattern.

What I am thinking of doing is to take several images by lens when mounted on a camera and compare the images, but I am not sure how I can process the images to find if lens is clean.

I tried to take an image from a say white box and look for pattern, but it was not successful, as the pattern is very faint and when I replace the lens, the change in image is bigger than the pattern to look for, so I am not getting correct result.

Any idea of what kind of image processing I can use to find if a lens is clean?

I want to write the software in c++ using openCV.

## Edit 1

The application is to test a camera with lens mounted on it. We are building camera modules with lens on them and we noted that sometimes there are some derbies on lens (or sensor) and we can not detect them easily.
so the workflow is:
We put a lens over our sensor and then we need to check if there is any derbies or dust on sensor or lens before we can ship it. We can test for dust before or after focusing, which ever is simpler (preferably before focusing as cleaning means we need to remove lens and clean it and put it back which requires a new focusing.)
We are doing it manually now by looking at the image generated by sensor on a computer and move the camera against a white paper and look for static patterns. Now we are looking for a way to do this using software.

Comment: post sample images. will the camera/lens be static once mounted? will you be able/allowed to provide (clean) reference images to the camera?

Comment: How many images you think to use? Have you considered analyzing videos?

Comment: I assume you mean "quick and *objective*", right?

Comment: @Micka I can mount the camera/lens or move them, so any way that helps is good. I can not provide the images taken by the same lens from the same location when the lens is clean and dirty, so a background subtraction would not work.

Comment: @Nyavro Yes I can get video too. The camera is a usb camera so I can take as many image that I want.

Comment: @Maljam Yes, I mean that and hence I wrote quick and subjective FREE way to do this. Am I wrong to say it that way?

Comment: This question is not software-related in the first place. The real issue is imaging conditions. And advising a processing method is completely elusive without seeing sample images (both clean and dirty).

Comment: @mans oops, my bad, I didn't see the "free".

Comment: I don't see how a video could ease the task at all. The pattern is static, isn't it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes the pattern is static, but if we can move the camera and capturing several images (possibly video) we should be able to see the static pattern. This is the way that we can detect the dust on lens when looking at the video of a completely white scene.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't have sample images now, but will post some very soon. I thought maybe there is a known method for this type of problem which is detecting a very faint static pattern on image.

Comment: @mans: if the lens is mounted on the camera it moves with the camera and there's no change.

Comment: please tell us more about the application target. do you want to let a program decide whether lens is dirty without assumptions of how the image looks like (e.g. without kmowing what kind of images the end user will present)?

Comment: so you are free to implement "any" test method, including fixed patterns etc? this might be a much easier scenario than I expected first. Does the "white paper" thing work on manual inspection? Would be very important to have some sample images to get an idea. MAYBE the averaged image gradient on a moved white paper could do the trick, maybe not.

Comment: I would try black background (very dark) with White grid on it (very thin lines). Ideally in dark room and lines would be the only source of light. Then check the thickness of the lines. if Lens is dirty or scratched it should create blurred halo in that area. But as been mentioned detect problems on already mounted lens is difficult due to heavy blurring which can affect focus and many different things during the picture acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

When the lens is mounted on the camera, you're not focused on the lens surface and the pattern is completely blurred.

You must look at the lens in the same conditions that you do with naked eye, possibly with a grazing incidence (?), and with a suitable background and a suitable lighting.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean? What type of algorithm do you suggest?

Comment: I never ever suggest image processing algorithms without seeing samples. This is a nonsense. And a software-only approach is deemed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas to experiment with...

Try multiple images of a very-nearly-uniformly white background, each with the camera ever-so-slightly moved (or even rotated).  My intuition is that a white piece of paper is likely to be more nearly uniform than an illuminated panel of any kind.  Using a smaller aperture setting may help minimise the amount by which dirt on the sensor is blurred over more pixels at the sensor - I'd suggest you explore this experimentally.  If you're not using a tripod, try to have bright enough light that you're not creating motion blur (e.g. at 100mm focal length, a shutter speed faster than 1/100th of a second).

As a quick check of potential, load the photos in an editor such as the gimp, and try to adjust the image levels so some of the image is close to black and other bits closer to white: if there's a noticable radial gradient, your lens is probably just darker towards the edges; if there's a gradiant from side to side, the light on your paper is likely uneven.  If there's speckling at the pixel level, that's great - your lens is probably very clean.  If there're some noticeable blotches, that's somewhere the lens may be dirty....

To confirm, we can turn to a software approach and carefully test multiple images, each slightly offset or rotated from the others.  If you un-move / un-rotate the images in software: shifting them until you minimise the overall image delta (e.g. the sum of the squares of the differences between pixel values).  After aligning the images in that way, you can adjust for radial/side-to-side gradiants / shadows etc. across the paper.  After that, if you get lower pixel values at the same pixel coordinates in all the images, it's suggestive of a lens (or sensor?) problem there.